# Se puede utilizar el operador and dentro de un foreach?

Tags: php

Me gustaria hacerlo de la siguiente forma:
**foreach($productores as $productor && $direcciones as $direccion)**

Comment: No creo amigo, el simbolo && es un operador de comparacion y retornara true o false.
Imaginate: foreach(true) no te lleva a nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foreach` es una estructura para iterar arreglos y objetos, no admite condiciones y funciona con un único elemento.

Suponiendo que ambos arreglos son numéricos, puedes recorrer uno y usar el índice para acceder al otro:

```
$productores = ['Productor 1', 'Productor 2', 'Productor 3'];
$direcciones = ['Dirección 1', 'Dirección 2', 'Dirección 3'];

foreach($productores as $index => $productor) {
    echo $productor; // Aunque también puede ser $productores[$index]
    echo $direcciones[$index];
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio tu ayuda, aunque no fueron numericos mis arreglos solo adapte tu respuesta a mi necesitad.

Answer (score 2):

Según la documentación oficial solo hay 2 usos posibles para el `foreach`

```
1. foreach (expresión_array as $valor)
    sentencias

2. foreach (expresión_array as $clave => $valor)
    sentencias
```

Por lo que no se puede utilizar el operador `and` dentro de la declaración del `foreach`

Mas información:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php